# Visual Studio Code Analysis on .Net Framework Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I am attempting to enable code analysis via Nuget for an existing .Net Framework 4.72 Web Application. To be frank, the documentation has me confused as to which packages to install.

I have installed **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers** via nuget.

The following is in my csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    ...
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
```

This code is loaded with problems, but I only the following two items are listed:

```
warning CA2237: Add [Serializable] to ParseException as this type implements ISerializable
warning CA1001: Type 'Repository' owns disposable field(s) '_context' but is not disposable
```

Are there other packages to load ?

Comment: If you install the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` NuGet package, you should not add the `EnableNETAnalyzers` property to either your project file or a `Directory.Build.props` file. When the NuGet package is installed and the `EnableNETAnalyzers` property is set to `true`, a build warning is generated.
Please see this article for more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview#code-style-analysis

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing `CA***` diagnostics, then it's working.

You can turn on more diagnostics in your projects via the "Dependencies" tree (expand the analyzers node).

Also, you have to add this `PackageReference` and associated properties to each project in your solution. You might like to do this in a `Directory.Build.props` file.

Why do you think you should be seeing more diagnostics?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the **References\Analyzers** node of the .Net Framework project.
I can verify the presence of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.
The rules now default to minimum, which means there are only 2 issues in my app.

Right click on **Analyzers|Open Active Ruleset...** and the rules can be customized.

It did not help this legacy project is a little wonky. I had to make a new project and pull in the Analyzer peices.